# Undefined reference error when using a simple class inside my function

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++, poco

I am getting nuts with this error so I thought some of more experienced developers can help me in this regard.
I am trying to compile a sample project which uses a C++ library (named Poco). My project is linked to compiled poco libraries.

Below is my (most simplified) code:

```
#include "Poco/UUID.h"
class x
{
    void func1()                                        
    {                                                                           
        new Poco::UUID();  //A
    }   
};

void func1()                                        
{                                                                           
    new Poco::UUID();   //B
}
```

Now when above code is compiled, line 'A' has no error but for line 'B' linker says:
**undefined reference to `Poco::UUID::UUID()'**

What is the reason? When I instantiate a class from external lib in a class method no error occurs but the same code in a function produces linker error? (When I comment line B, no error occurs and linker output files are generated)

My configuration: Win7/g++/CodeLite/MinGW-4.7.1

**Update 2:**Thanks. My problem is now resolved and the issue is that I had compiled library using MSVC compiler while my application was being compiled using g++ (both under Windows platform). So I re-compiled library using g++ and everything works fine now.

**Update 1:** here is my IDE's output when I build my project:

```
    C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  "dll1.mk"  all"
----------Building project:[ dll1 - Debug ]----------
g++ -shared -fPIC -o ./Debug/dll1.so @"dll1.txt" -L. -Lc:/poco/lib  -lPocoFoundationd
./Debug/PluginLibrary.o: In function `Z5func1v':
C:/Users/PARS/Documents/codelite/workspace1/dll1/PluginLibrary.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Poco::UUID::UUID()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Debug/dll1.so] Error 1
dll1.mk:77: recipe for target `Debug/dll1.so' failed
1 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: can you post how you compile your code?

Comment: You are probably just not linking the relevant library.

Comment: If the problem is not linking to the relevant library, why my code is compiled and linked without any issue when I comment line 'B'?

Comment: Do you get the exact same error with the "most simplified code" that you posted? (In particular, no `template` or `DLLEXPORT` things?) Also, is it all in `PluginLibrary.cpp`?

Comment: The code that I posted is all there is in my project and I get mentioned error when I build my project.

Comment: Then why is the error pointing line `16` while you code is at line `12`?

Comment: I fixed the log. I think the output log belonged to a modified version. Now error message points to line #12

Comment: What do you include in file with B? You shoud check your includes and namespaces. Maybe you are including somethnig twice ?

Comment: Please also notice your function in class is inline function and check this stackoverflow.com/questions/12154321/c-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-not-inline-defined-functions do you still get linker error after making your second function inline too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your member function `x::func1()` is never *ODR-used* in that compilation unit (source file). Most compilers only generate compiled code for a member function defined inside the class definition if that member function is *ODR-used* within the compilation unit that is being compiled. Suppose some other source file does use `x::func1()`. If you compile that other source file, the compiler will produce object code for `x::func1()` in the object file that corresponds to that other source file.

The compiler can get away with bypassing the process of generating compiled code for `x::func1()` here because the class definition has to be the same across all compilation units. If you compile some other source file that has a different definition of class x you have violated the one definition rule. This is undefined behavior and no diagnosis is required.

If no source file uses `x::func1()` you have some dead code that just never happens to be compiled. The code has an error but it's never detected.

The compiler cannot get away with bypassing generating compiled code for the free function `func1()`. This function has external linkage; there's no way the compiler can tell if it might be used somewhere else. The compiler must generate compiled code for that free function.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
class Missing {
public:
   Missing();
   int value;
};

class UsesMissing {
public:

   int use_missing () {
      Missing missing;
      return missing.value;
   }

   int dont_use_missing () {
      return 0;
   }
};

#ifdef DEFINE_USE_MISSING
int use_missing () {
   Missing missing;
   return missing.value;
}
#endif

int main () {
   UsesMissing test;
#ifdef USE_MISSING
   return test.use_missing();
#else
   return test.dont_use_missing();
#endif
}
```

Compile with neither `DEFINE_USE_MISSING` or `USE_MISSING` defined and this compiles and links just fine with g++ and clang++. Define either one of those flags and the file fails in the link step because of the undefined reference `Missing::Missing()`.

Comment: I have no issue with x::func1 because it produces no error. I just wrote this class to show that no problem exists if I instantiate UUID class inside a class method. My issue is with func1 which is not inside the class which raises an undefined reference error.

Comment: @mahdix - You have no issue with `x::func1` because it's never used. If you use that member function somewhere you will have a problem. To solve this problem you need to link with the Poco library.

Comment: That's right. I think I am not linking with appropriate poco lib

Comment: @mahdix: which is *exactly* what I said in my comment back when you first posted your question...

Comment: "_ODE-used_" I guess you meant _ODR-used_ (damn formatting I can't manage to highlight the R) ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/5565522 ) (btw ODR stands for _One Definition Rule_)

Comment: @gx_ - You're right. I'm writing up on how our simulation engine handles various ordinary differential equations (ODEs). I must have made a mental slip in typing this answer. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should link with the correct library to fix your link (see Poco docu for the correct one).

func1 has extern linkage and so linker need Poco::UUID
whereas X::func1 is inline/private/unused.

if you use `static foo1()` or `inline foo1()` the linker error disappears
if you use `x::func1` or implement `x::func1` outside of the `class x{};` the error linker appears

Comment: That's right. I get error for both usages of UUID class if I implement x::func1 outside of class body. But I think I am linking with correct Poco libraries (PocoFoundationmdd.lib) according to the docs.

Comment: You should not use msvc library with gcc/g++